# Export 3D climate data to a netCDF file in R

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I have a problem with exporting gridded daily climate data into netCDF. I first create some random data, export it as netCDF, then reopen it and plot the time series before and after export. Both lines should match, but instead one line is always constant.
There must be a bug in how I write the netCDF file, but I just can not find a solution, even though I have analysed most of the examples available online.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# create some example data
dates = seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"), length.out = 365, by="1 day")
lon = seq(-180.00, 180.00, by = 10)
lat = seq(0,90, by = 10)
tmp_df <- expand.grid(date = dates, lon = lon, lat = lat)
tmp_df$t2m <- rnorm(15, 15, n = nrow(tmp_df)) + 272.15   # some random Kelvins 

# export data as netCDF  
xvals <- unique(tmp_df$lon)
nx <- length(xvals)
  
yvals <- unique(tmp_df$lat) 
ny <- length(yvals)
  
lon1 <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees_east", xvals)
lat2 <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_north", yvals)
  
time <-unique(tmp_df$date)
n_time <- length(time)
dimtime <- ncdim_def("time", "days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00", as.numeric(time),
                     unlim=T, calendar="gregorian")

# different sorting options, none of them works properly
vals <- dplyr::arrange(tmp_df, lon, lat, date) 
# vals <- dplyr::arrange(tmp_df, date, lon, lat) 
# vals <- dplyr::arrange(tmp_df, lat, lon, date)
vals <- vals$t2m
  
mv <- -999 #missing value to use
var_temp <- ncvar_def("t2m", "K", list(lon1, lat2, dimtime), longname = "test.nc", mv) 
ncnew <- nc_create("test.nc", list(var_temp))
ncvar_put(ncnew, var_temp, as.array(vals), start=c(1,1,1), count=c(nx,ny,n_time))
nc_close(ncnew)
  
###############################################################################

# save data from one random grid point for the comparison  
ts1 <- dplyr::filter(tmp_df, lon < 1, lon > -1, lat < 1)
ts1$source <- 'initial'
  
##############################################################################
# Open the nc file  
nc2 <- nc_open("test.nc")
  
# get longitude and latitude
lon <- ncvar_get(nc2,"longitude")
nlon <- dim(lon)
  
lat <- ncvar_get(nc2,"latitude")
nlat <- dim(lat)
  
time <- ncvar_get(nc2,"time")
tunits <- ncatt_get(nc2,"time","units")
nt <- dim(time)

tmp_array <- ncvar_get( nc2, "t2m", start= c(1, 1, 1), 
                          count = c(nlon, nlat, nt))
  
tmp_vec_long <- as.vector(tmp_array)
tmp_mat <- matrix(tmp_vec_long, nrow=nlon*nlat, ncol=nt)
lonlat <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lon,lat))
  
tmp_df02 <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat,tmp_mat))
names(tmp_df02)[1:2] <- c("lon","lat")
colnames(tmp_df02)[3:ncol(tmp_df02)] <- time
  
tmp_df02 <- reshape2::melt(tmp_df02, id.vars = c("lon", "lat"))

# convert back to Date
tmp_df02$date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(time*24*60*60, origin = "1970-01-01"))
tmp_df02$variable <- NULL

nc_close(nc2)
  
##############################################################################
# extract the same point data as before
ts2 <- dplyr::filter(tmp_df02, lon < 1, lon > -1, lat < 1)
ts2$source <- 'after'

# rbind now and before  
ts <- rbind(ts1,rename(ts2, "t2m" = "value"))

# plot initial and after values: both lines should overlap
ggplot(ts, aes(x = date, y = t2m, col = source)) + geom_line()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: there was an issue related to the arrangement of lon, lat and time variables. Working script is posted below.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# create some example data
dates = seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"), length.out = 365, by="1 day")
lon = seq(-180.00, 180.00, by = 10)
lat = seq(0,90, by = 10)
tmp_df <- expand.grid(date = dates, lon = lon, lat = lat)
tmp_df$t2m <- rnorm(15, 15, n = nrow(tmp_df)) + 272.15   # some random Kelvins 

# export data as netCDF  
xvals <- unique(tmp_df$lon)
nx <- length(xvals)
  
yvals <- unique(tmp_df$lat) 
ny <- length(yvals)
  
lon1 <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees_east", xvals)
lat2 <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_north", yvals)
  
time <-unique(tmp_df$date)
n_time <- length(time)
dimtime <- ncdim_def("time", "days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00", as.numeric(time),
                     unlim=T, calendar="gregorian")

vals <- dplyr::arrange(tmp_df, date, lat, lon) 
vals <- vals$t2m
mat1 <- array(vals, c(nx, ny, n_time));  

mv <- -999 #missing value to use
var_temp <- ncvar_def("t2m", "K", list(lon1, lat2, dimtime), longname = "test.nc", mv) 
ncnew <- nc_create("test.nc", list(var_temp))
ncvar_put(ncnew, var_temp, mat1, start=c(1,1,1), count=c(nx,ny,n_time))
nc_close(ncnew)
  
###############################################################################

# save data from one random grid point for the comparison  
ts1 <- dplyr::filter(tmp_df, lon < 1, lon > -1, lat < 1)
ts1$source <- 'initial'
  
##############################################################################
# Open the nc file  
nc2 <- nc_open("test.nc")
  
# get longitude and latitude
lon <- ncvar_get(nc2,"longitude")
nlon <- dim(lon)
  
lat <- ncvar_get(nc2,"latitude")
nlat <- dim(lat)
  
time <- ncvar_get(nc2,"time")
tunits <- ncatt_get(nc2,"time","units")
nt <- dim(time)

tmp_array <- ncvar_get( nc2, "t2m", start= c(1, 1, 1), 
                          count = c(nlon, nlat, nt))
  
tmp_vec_long <- as.vector(tmp_array)

tmp_df02 <- melt(mat1)

mat1 <- array(tmp_vec_long, c(nlon, nlat, nt));  
tmp_mat <- matrix(tmp_vec_long, nrow=nlon*nlat, ncol=nt)
lonlat <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lon,lat))
tmp_df02 <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat,tmp_mat))
names(tmp_df02)[1:2] <- c("lon","lat")
colnames(tmp_df02)[3:ncol(tmp_df02)] <- time
tmp_df02 <- reshape2::melt(tmp_df02, id.vars = c("lon", "lat"))
colnames(tmp_df02)[1:3] <- c("lon", "lat", "date")

# convert back to Date
tmp_df02$date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(tmp_df02$date))*24*60*60, origin = "1970-01-01"))

# tmp_df02$variable <- NULL
nc_close(nc2)
  
##############################################################################
# extract the same point data as before
ts2 <- dplyr::filter(tmp_df02, lon < 1, lon > -1, lat < 1)
ts2$source <- 'after'

# rbind now and before  
ts <- rbind(ts1,rename(ts2, "t2m" = "value"))

# plot initial and after values: both lines should overlap
ggplot(ts, aes(x = date, y = t2m, col = source)) + geom_line()

# another test
dcast(ts, formula = date ~ source, value.var = "t2m")
```

Comment: You might put a little more explicity `# this is where my script jumped the rails because...` for future readers as netCDF comes up rather often.